# jQuery - Create container around headings and next block element that is not header

Tags: jquery

I want to wrap heading(s) and the first non-heading block element that follows the heading(s) in a single div so that I can control page breaks and ensure headings are printed with the proceeding text.

Example 1:

```
<h1>Main title</h1>
<h2>Sub title</h2>
<h3>Another sub title</h3>
<p>Paragraph text here...</p>
<p>And more paragraph text here</p>
```

would become

```
<div class="PrintTogether">
    <h1>Main title</h1>
    <h2>Sub title</h2>
    <h3>Another sub title</h3>
    <p>Paragraph text here...</p>
</div>
<p>And more paragraph text here</p>
```

Example 2:

```
<h2>Some title</h2>
<ol>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
</ol>
<p>And more paragraph text here</p>
```

would become

```
<div class="PrintTogether">
    <h2>Some title</h2>
    <ol>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ol>
</div>
<p>And more paragraph text here</p>
```

The jQuery I have put together so far is:

```
$('h1, h2, h3, h4').each(function() {
    // ignore if header is already wrapped in PrintTogether div
    if (! $(this).parents('.PrintTogether').length ) {
        $(this).nextUntil('p, ol, ul, table').andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="PrintTogether" />');
    }
});
```

My issue is that I cannot get the last element (`<p>` or `<ol>` in the examples above) to be included in the PrintTogether div. This is what I am currently getting:

```
<div class="PrintTogether">
    <h1>Main title</h1>
    <h2>Sub title</h1>
    <h3>Another sub title</h3>
</div> <!-- should be after next p block -->
<p>Paragraph text here...</p>
<p>And more paragraph text here</p>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the next element after the generated `.PrintTogether` wrapper and move it inside the wrapper too.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('h1, h2, h3, h4').each(function() {
    // ignore if header is already wrapped in PrintTogether div

    if (!$(this).parents('.PrintTogether').length) {
      var headings = $(this).nextUntil('p, ol, ul, table').andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="PrintTogether" />');
      var wrapper = headings.eq(0).parent();
      wrapper.next().appendTo(wrapper);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.PrintTogether {
  background-color: rgba(50,50,60,.2);
  padding:15px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>title</h1>
<h2>Some title</h2>
<h3>Some title</h3>
<h4>Some title</h4>
<ol>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ol>
<p>And more paragraph text here</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the assist. I was able to get it working using your suggested approach.

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude the first paragraph I guess.

Check the updated code below. Hope this helps!

```
$('h1, h2, h3, h4').each(function() {
// ignore if header is already wrapped in PrintTogether div
if (! $(this).parents('.PrintTogether').length ) {
    $(this).nextUntil('ol, ul, table,p:not(:first)').andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="PrintTogether" />');
}
});
```

If `p` is the always first element expected after div `.PrintTogether` then you can use `nextUntil('p:not(:first)')` only.